# How response to client on azure mobile services?

Tags: azure, windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure mobile services and windows phone client. I don't have idea to response client here

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
    {
        TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);


        //response to client ?
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use Mobile Apps instead of Mobile Services as they will be discontinued.

2) Mobile Apps is the mobile-backend-as-a-service which have the API consisted of standard HTTP verbs (GET, POST, etc). Every HTTP verb has the script associated with that that can be written using C#/Node.js on the backend side. That code is being executed every time that HTTP verb is "executed" by the client.

3) For being able to respond to the client, you should invoke the HTTP verb, then the script associated with that in a backend will be executed and if you will get the response as a HTTP response. [Here is the overview you would want to take a look at.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/)

4) A little code in the backend that is doing what you need:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
if (item.userId !== user.userId) {
    request.respond(statusCodes.FORBIDDEN, 
    'You may only insert records with your userId.');
} else {
    request.execute();
}}
```

request.respond is the needed code - your client will get what you will place here.